# Enable button after input text field generated by jquery is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adding of text field are generated by jquery. I just want to enable the submit button after the input text field are typed in. Thanks. Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/akoni/kL8jdpdc/

I tried this code, but no luck.

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('body').find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if (($(this).val() == '')) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})()
```

Comment: you try this url http://jsfiddle.net/yy4jr8qn/3/ or http://fiddle.jshell.net/K5Pfj/

Comment: Console in fiddle says `Uncaught ReferenceError: select_all is not defined`

Comment: Perhaps change $('body').find('input[type="text"]') to $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="text"]') so you only query text inputs within the form

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, but that's not what I want. The thing is that all inputs are generated by jquery not in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use delegation binding for any html elements that is dynamically added.

> Try change `$('form > input').keyup(function() {`
>
> to `$('form').on('keyup','input',function() {`

Good luck!

Comment: Yes!! This is what I want. Thank you bro.. My complete code is
(function() {
$('form').on('keyup','input',function() {
     var empty = false;
        $('body').find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if (($(this).val() == '')) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
});
})()

Comment: @enrique I'm glad to help you with such simple answer :D then please mark this as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you actually faced explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements), basically you should use `on()` instead of `keyup()`. And

```
input[type="text"]
```

will return less count then `form > input`, here is the changes

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input[type='text']", function() {
  var empty = false;
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if (($(this).val() == '')) {
      empty = true;
    }
  });

  if (empty) {
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle result](https://jsfiddle.net/kL8jdpdc/14/)

Hope helps,

Comment: We should not use `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()` for element props like 'disabled', 'readonly', 'checked', etc. We should use `.prop()`. And we also better use single line code, e.g. `$('#submit').prop('disabled',empty);`

Answer (score 0):

This should right about do it:

```
(function() {
$("form > input").keyup(function() {
    var text = $("form > input").val();

    if (text == "") {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, but that's not what I want. The thing is that all inputs are generated by jquery not in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/kL8jdpdc/9/

```js
(function() {
    $('form').on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    
        var empty = false;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if (($(this).val() == '')) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()


var i=1;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
  $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 count=$('table tr').length;
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>";
    data +="<td><input type='hidden' id='process_id"+i+"' name='process_name"+i+"'/>P"+i+"</td><td><input type='text' id='burst_id"+i+"' class='text-input-grey' name='burst_name"+i+"'/></td></tr>";
 $('table').append(data);
 i++;
});

function select_all() {
 $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
  if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
   $(this).prop("checked", false); 
  } else {
   $(this).prop("checked", true); 
  } 
 });
}


$(".delete").on('click', function() {
 $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post' action='' class='subscription-table'>

<table width="500" align='center' border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
    <th>Process</th>
    <th>Burst Time</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add Process</button>

           <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

Use `$('form').on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]'` instead of `$('form > input')`, if you select only `input` then it will select checkboxes as well.

When you add a new row, you need to disable the submit button as well `$('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` added to the click event of `.addmore` button.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: WOW!! Yeah. Yours is correct too. Thank you bro. Sadly I can't upvote any answer here. But thank you Shiladitya. I love you hehe